# Database fragment query error "parameters must be of length 0 for query"

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I am trying to query a json array in the `building` table, jsonb `metadata` column, and within `google_place_ids` property, which is an array.

Elixir is giving me an error:

Here's the query the fragment is generating:

```
SELECT b0."id", b0."base_sku", b0."name", b0."logo", b0."email", b0."active", b0."sync", b0."building_group_id", b0."operating_region_id", b0."building_package_id", b0."metadata", b0."location", b0."inserted_at", b0."updated_at" FROM "buildings" AS b0 WHERE (b0."metadata"->'google_place_ids' @> '["$1"]') AND (b0."active" = TRUE) ["1234231223123"]
```

Here's the code:

```
defp query_by_google_place_id(query, google_place_id) do
from(b in query,
    where: fragment("?->'google_place_ids' @> '[\"?\"]'", b.metadata,  ^google_place_id),
    where: b.active == true,
    limit: 1)
end
```

Here is the error:

```
[error] #PID<0.1340.0> running Proxy.InstrumentedPlug terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /something/google_place_id/1234231223123
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) parameters must be of length 0 for query %Postgrex.Query{columns:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how PostgreSQL will understand it. The problem is that Ecto's `fragment` do not know anything about SQL (or other query language) you can use there, so it ends treating `?` as a query parameter while PostgreSQL treats it as a raw string `"$1"`. What you need to do is to pass string directly in form of:

```
fragment("?->'google_place_ids' @> ?", b.metadata, ^"[\"#{google_place_id}\"]")
```

Comment: This prevents the error from happening but isn't returning anything, and I'm sure the query should work because it works with `where: fragment("?->'google_place_ids' @> '[\"EXAMPLE\"]'", b.metadata)` where the id is directly in the query.

Comment: You are still messing the things. This one works, because you insert the data directly into the fragment, but it will not work with data being inserted dynamically. If you are familiar with C then it will work like preprocessor macro expansion: it will not be expanded within strings.

Answer (score 0):

This works, less quotes and no brackets

```
defp query_by_google_place_id(query, google_place_id) do
    from(b in query,
        where: fragment("?->'google_place_ids' @> ?", b.metadata, ^google_place_id),
        where: b.active == true,
        limit: 1)
end
```